# Can not add admin notices from the edit_user_profile_update hook (notices not being displayed)?

Tags: php, hooks, admin, actions, notices

Writing a little plugin my code is like this:

```
add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', 'sulock_save_profile_fields' );

function sulock_save_profile_fields( $user_being_edited_id ) {

    if(update_user_meta( $user_being_edited_id, 'sulock_permanently_locked', $permlock)) {
        update_user_meta($user_being_edited_id, 'sulock_permlock_meta',new Sulock\LockMeta());
        if($permlock) {
            sulock_admin_notice(__('This user has been permanently locked by you.',SULOCK_TEXTDOMAIN),'notice notice-warning');
        } else {
            sulock_admin_notice(__('This user has been permanently locked by you.',SULOCK_TEXTDOMAIN),'notice notice-warning');
        }
    }
}

// a simplified function for admin notices
function sulock_admin_notice($message,$class) {
    add_action('admin_notices',function() use ($message,$class) {
        printf( '<div class="%1$s"><p>%2$s</p></div>', esc_attr( $class ), esc_html( $message ) );
    });
}
```

The `sulock_admin_notice()` function is working if called from the code directly, but if I call it from the hook the notice is never shown. Nethertheless *I assume that the hook is executed before the UI is loaded and therefore the admin notices should be registered*.

Whats going wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: the problem is that the `admin_notices` hook is executed before your profile edit hook is fired so you're adding actions to a hook that will not be fired again.

Comment: Not sure I thougt it should be before. But I will try again and report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WordPress redirects you back to the `user-edit.php` page upon successful user update, so while the `admin_notices` has yet been fired in your `sulock_save_profile_fields()`, the message (your custom admin notice) is never displayed *because of the redirection*.

And one way to fix it, is by filtering the redirect URL via the `wp_redirect` [filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_redirect/):

```php
// In sulock_save_profile_fields()
if ( update_user_meta( $user_being_edited_id, 'sulock_permanently_locked', $permlock ) ) {
    update_user_meta( $user_being_edited_id, 'sulock_permlock_meta', new Sulock\LockMeta() );

    add_filter( 'wp_redirect', function( $location ) use ( $permlock ) {
        return add_query_arg( 'permlock', $permlock, $location );
    } );
}
```

Then hook to `load-user-edit.php` which is fired when the `user-edit.php` page is loaded, and add the admin notice from there: (the `updated` item below is set by WordPress)

```php
add_action( 'load-user-edit.php', function(){
    if ( ! empty( $_GET['updated'] ) && isset( $_GET['permlock'] ) ) {
        if ( $_GET['permlock'] ) {
            sulock_admin_notice(__('Message here.', SULOCK_TEXTDOMAIN), 'notice notice-warning');
        } else {
            sulock_admin_notice(__('Message here.', SULOCK_TEXTDOMAIN), 'notice notice-warning');
        }
    }
} );
```

**Alternatively, you could (or might want to) use the [transients API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Transients_API):**

```php
// In sulock_save_profile_fields()
if ( update_user_meta( $user_being_edited_id, 'sulock_permanently_locked', $permlock ) ) {
    update_user_meta( $user_being_edited_id, 'sulock_permlock_meta', new Sulock\LockMeta() );

    set_transient( 'su_updated', [ 'permlock' => $permlock ], 30 );
}
```

And the hook:

```php
add_action( 'load-user-edit.php', function(){
    if ( ! empty( $_GET['updated'] ) ) {
        $data = get_transient( 'su_updated' );
        if ( $data && $data['permlock'] ) {
            sulock_admin_notice(__('Message here.', SULOCK_TEXTDOMAIN), 'notice notice-warning');
        } elseif ( $data ) { // the transient exists (not expired)
            sulock_admin_notice(__('Message here.', SULOCK_TEXTDOMAIN), 'notice notice-warning');
        }
    }
} );
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this detailed explanation 